# Mock modules that has a class and other attributes

Tags: unit-testing, twilio, jestjs

I'm trying to mock `twilio` module but it's being a pain. I'm new to Jest and I've read docs but it's not clear how should I mock a class and a type.

This is the code that I'm trying to mock:

```
const Twilio = require('twilio')
const client = new Twilio('sid', 'auth')
const response = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse()
```

The part of constructor `new Twilio` is doing fine:

```
jest.mock('twilio', () => class {
  constructor (accountSid, authToken) {
    this.conferences = {
      list () {
        return mockTwilioListConferences()
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But how can I mock the part `new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse()`?

Comment: Why do you need to mock the `VoiceResponse`? It doesn't make external requests, just generates XML for you.

Comment: @philnash because I've mocked entire module twilio. I don't know how to mock just a function from module.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Disclaimer, I haven't tried this, but here's how I believe this works.

The `twiml` property on the `Twilio` class is just that, a property. In your mock you instantly return a new anonymous class, but if you add the property to the class itself before you return you should find it is then part of your mock.

For example:

```
jest.mock('twilio', () => {
  const mockClass = class {
    constructor (accountSid, authToken) {
      this.conferences = {
        list () {
          return mockTwilioListConferences()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  mockClass.twiml = {
    // complete your mock implementation here
  }
  return mockClass;
);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.